# jquery pass text and variable inside .html()

Tags: jquery

this is probably very easy but I can't figure it out :)

```
 $('#myDiv').html('<a onclick="remove_item(variantId);">Remove</a>');
```

variantId is a JS variable so I need to pass it's value in the code above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $('#myDiv').html('<a onclick="remove_item(' + variantId + ');">Remove</a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

use it this way -

```
 $('#myDiv').html('<a onclick="remove_item('+variantId+');">Remove</a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myDiv').html('<a onclick="remove_item('+variantId+');">Remove</a>');
```